# How to read and process data from a set of text files sequentially?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-files

I have 50 text files (namely `Force1.txt`, `Force2.txt`, ..., `Force50.txt`). The files look like this:

```
0.0000000e+000 -1.4275799e-003  
2.0000000e-002 -1.1012760e-002  
4.0000000e-002 -1.0298970e-002  
6.0000000e-002 -8.9733599e-003  
8.0000000e-002 -9.6871497e-003  
1.0000000e-001 -1.2236400e-002  
1.2000000e-001 -1.4479739e-002  
1.4000000e-001 -1.3052160e-002  
1.6000000e-001 -1.1216700e-002  
1.8000000e-001 -8.6674497e-003  
2.0000000e-001 -8.6674497e-003  
2.2000000e-001 -1.3358070e-002  
2.4000000e-001 -1.7946720e-002  
2.6000000e-001 -1.9782179e-002
```

I wish to read data from `Force1.txt`, store data in a list of tuples, and analize these data (the details of such analysis are not relevant to the question). Then I have to do the same with `Force2.txt`, `Force3.txt`, and so on.

Here is my attempt:

```
def load_data(fn):
    with open(fn) as f:    
        lines = f.readlines()
    return [tuple(map(float, x)) for x in [row.split() for row in lines]]
def display_data(lst):
    return lst.__repr__().replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
pp = []
for file in os.listdir("dir"):
    if file.endswith('.txt'):
        if file.startswith('Force'):    
            print os.path.join(r"dir", file)     
            with open(file) as f:     
                for line in f:  
                    pp.append(map(float, line.split()))
mdb.models['Model-1'].TabularAmplitude(data=pp, name='Table', smooth=SOLVER_DEFAULT, timeSpan=STEP)
```

I'm getting this error:

> 'Table', smooth=SOLVER_DEFAULT, timeSpan=STEP):
>   **Invalid time values, expected monotonically increasing numbers**

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: There is no issue with the code. However, I want to run in loops for the 50 files. How to modify the code?

Comment: What do you mean with *run in loops for the 50 files*. You already have a loop that visits all files that match the criterion. Are you asking to exit the loop after you have read the 50th file?

Comment: from the documentation: `os.listdir(path='.') Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by path. The list is in arbitrary order ...`.

Comment: ... **The list is in arbitrary order** ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do:

```
import os

def load_data(fn):
    with open(fn) as f:     
        lines = f.readlines() 
    return [tuple(map(float, x)) for x in [row.split() for row in lines]]

def display_data(lst):
    return lst.__repr__().replace('[', '').replace(']', '')

dirname = r"Your dir name goes here"

for filename in os.listdir(dirname):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        if filename.startswith('Force'):     
            pathfile = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
            print pathfile
            pp = load_data(pathfile)
            print display_data(pp)    
            mdb.models['Model-1'].TabularAmplitude(data=pp, 
                                                   name='Table', 
                                                   smooth=SOLVER_DEFAULT, 
                                                   timeSpan=STEP)
```

You just need to update `dirname` with the name of the directory which contains the text files. I recommend you not to use `file` as a variable identifier because `file` is a reserved word in Python. I've used `filename` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the modification. But there is an error "Invalid Time values, expected monotonically increasing numbers". How to solve this?

Comment: The code above reads the text files correctly (this is what you asked in your question). I'm afraid the error you mention is caused by the content of the text files. If the content of the text files is not adequate for further processing, you will get an error in the call to `mdb.models['Model-1'].TabularAmplitude`

Comment: What I feel is that after the 1st iteration (from reading data in file Force1), it is unable to do the same with file Force2 as the data conversion (reading from file and converting into required format) is not in loop. Should that be the issue?

Comment: Please, edit your question and add the full error message and traceback

Comment: The indentation of your code is incorrect. Try the code as it is in my answer.

Comment: Copy-paste the code in my ANSWER and put the name of the directory that contains the text files in `dirname`. This shoul work.

Comment: Does `pp` get printed?

Comment: It is printing all the data of the 50 files [(0,1), (0.1, 2), ..., (1, 10), (0.1, 2), (0.2, 4), ... , ]. You can see after the last value of the 1st file (1, 10) it is taking the 1st value of the 2nd file (0.1, 2). But it should not print like this. This data set is causing the problem in mdb.models()...

I am repeating again: The code should take the data set from the 1st file, put in pp, run the analysis for pp, give the output, then use 2nd file and repeat.

Comment: You didn't clearly state this in the original question. I edited my answer to meet the new problem statement.